# Duplicate check before adding

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wish to apologize to everyone.

And thank everyone.

It seems I was missing a stupid fricking var which I didn't even notice.
I thought it was my check which was broken but no I missed a var in an above method so it was just constantly saying yea it's true -.- Thanks everyone for helping

Comment: Are you missing braces around the last if-statement? The indentation is wrong/unclear.

Comment: Can you post the method `InsertItemIntoReceivedBoxesTable`? Are you checking against the correct column?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on your duplicate check, what does that tell you?

Comment: It just returns true, I've checked the debugger, It's fine . I give up, This website only knows things which don't relate to a gridview

Answer (score 0):

Dennis_E's answer was right. There should be braces around code "lblNotRawConsignmentNumber.Text = "BLAH";isDuplicate = true; break;". The method `IeTest()` will return true at first time, and then return false all the time.

Comment: Can you explain why that is?

Comment: You don't need { } at all, Because you can just invert the if statement to be

Comment: His purpose is to check the duplicate. If no braces, only the value of the first row to check. And the step of "isDuplicate = true;" 
will execute, no matter whether there is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `return;` after each check. Because now you do the checks but after that nothing stops you code to execute. You have to do something like this:

```
protected void BoxReceivedClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lblSupporterId.Text == "")
    {
        lblNotRawConsignmentNumber.Text = "Cannot Insert! Missing SupporterId";
        return;
    }
    else if (lblConsignmentNumber.Text == "")
    {
        lblNotRawConsignmentNumber.Text = "Cannot Insert! Missing Consignment Number";
        return;
    }
    else if (lblCollectionRequestId.Text == "")
    {
        lblNotRawConsignmentNumber.Text = "Cannot Insert! Missing Collection Request ID";
        return;
    }
    else if (Istest())
    {
        return;
    }

    InsertItemIntoReceivedBoxesTable(lblSupporterId.Text, txtReferenceNumber.Text, lblCollectionRequestId.Text);
    BindReceivedBoxes();
    ClearLabels();
}
```

Comment: I've done what you said, but it doesn't work at all now. doesn't add anything

Comment: Did you apply the suggestion from Byron?

Comment: I've done them both, Neither are working

Comment: What is the behavior when you click you button?

Comment: It's just a button, Once clicked it does what it's told..

Comment: Sorry I cannot help you because you're not providing enough information

Answer (score 0):

Actually your `Istest()` method returns `true` when it doesn't find duplicates, and `false` otherwise:

```
return !isDuplicate;
```

Remove the `!` from the return statement.

Comment: Tried this but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

In your program you check if the cell does **not** match the new value and then you assign `true` to `isDuplicate`. Then you assign the **Dupe Test** value to the `lblNotRawConsignmentNumber`

```
if (lblConsignmentNumber.Text != gvReceivedBoxes.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text)
{
  isDuplicate = true;
  lblNotRawConsignmentNumber.Text = "Dupe Teset";
  break;
}
```

try the following:

```
if (lblConsignmentNumber.Text == gvReceivedBoxes.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text)
{
  isDuplicate = true;
  lblNotRawConsignmentNumber.Text = "Dupe Teset";
  break;
}
```

Comment: I tried this way , Again It did not work...

Comment: Again, I've tried this way, When I change to " == " Instead of " != " It just allows me to post everything an anything